# Measuring execution time - gettimeofday versus clock() versus chrono

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a subroutine that should be executed once every milisecond. I wanted to check that indeed that's what's happening. But I get different execution times from different functions. I've been trying to understand the differences between these functions (there are several SO questions about the subject) but I cannot get my head around the results I got. Please forget the global variables etc. This is a legacy code, written in C, ported to C++, which I'm trying to improve, so is messy.

```
< header stuff>
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tchrono;
int64_t tgettime;
float tclock;

void myfunction(){

<all kinds of calculations>

  using ms = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>;
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tmpchrono = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  printf("chrono %f (ms): \n",std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(tmpchrono-tchrono).count());
  tchrono = tmpchrono;

  struct timeval tv;
  gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
  int64_t tmpgettime = (int64_t) tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
  printf("gettimeofday: %lld\n",tmpgettime-tgettime);
  tgettime = tmpgettime;

  float tmpclock = 1000.0f*((float)clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("clock %f (ms)\n",tmpclock-tclock);
  tclock = tmpclock;

  <more stuff>
}
```

and the output is:

```
chrono 0.998352 (ms): 
gettimeofday: 999
clock 0.544922 (ms)
```

Why the difference? I'd expect clock to be at least as large as the others, or not?

Comment: I dont understand your code. You are calling this function i a loop? As I understand this code, you are measuring the time that that passed between two exectutions of this timing code stuff, right? Usually I put the timing stuff around the code I want to measure and not the other way around.

Comment: The reason, why chrono shows zero is, because the duration cast is truncating the duration to whole milliseconds. Other than that I agree with tobi303 that this is a rather unusual way to measure execution time / benchmark your function, because you include the execution time of your printfs, which probably take longer than your functional code.

Comment: yep, your timing includes the printfs plus any other code that happens between two function calls. I am sorry, but before discussing the numbers you should fix this. Atm these numbers are anyhow quite meaningless.

Comment: Also, your `time_span` variable holds the duration in seconds, not milliseconds and finally, using a duration in a printf statement like that is either IB or UB (I believe the latter). Use `count()` to get the duration in the form of its underlying presentation (here double) and then use `%d` instead of `%f` in the printf.

Comment: The function is called in a loop. I don't want to measure the execution time, I want to measure the time between the calls. So yes, this is a wrong way to measure execution time but that's not what I'm doing. Thanks for the time_span info. I'll update the code, test it, and get back.

Comment: @MikeMB your comments are mostly correct, expect for  recommending`%d` for `double`, which is wrong because `%d` is meant for integers. It's an alias for `%i`. `%f` is correct for `double`. There is no separate format for `float` because it would be promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`.

Comment: @user2079303: Yes, you are right of course.

Comment: For the love of god use `auto`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() is not even working.

`std::chrono::milliseconds` represents the milliseconds as integers. When you convert to that representation, time representations of higher granularity are truncated to whole milliseconds. Then you assign it to a duration that has a `double` representation and seconds-ratio. Then you pass the `duration` object - instead of a `double` - to `printf`. All of those steps are wrong.

To get the milliseconds as a floating point, do this:

```
using ms = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>;
std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(tmpchrono-tchrono).count();
```

[clock()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) returns the processor time the process has used. That will depend on how much time the OS scheduler has given to your process. Unless the process is the only one on the system, this will be different from the passed wall clock time.

[gettimeofday()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) returns the wall clock time.

> What's the difference between using high_resolution_clock::now() and gettimeofday() ?

Both measure the wall clock time. The internal representation of both is implementation defined. The granularity of both is implementation defined as well.

`gettimeofday` is part of the POSIX standard and therefore available in all operating systems that comply with that standard (POSIX.1-2001). `gettimeofday` is not monotonic, i.e. it's affected by things like setting the time (by ntpd or by adminstrator) and changes in daylight saving time.

> `high_resolution_clock` represents the clock with the smallest tick period provided by the implementation. It may be an alias of std::chrono::system_clock or std::chrono::steady_clock, or a third, independent clock.

`high_resolution_clock` is part of the c++ standard library and therefore available in all compilers that comply with that standard (c++11). `high_resolution_clock` may or might not be monotonic. This can be tested with `high_resolution_clock::is_steady`

Comment: That helped. What's the difference between using high_resolution_clock::now() and gettimeofday() ? That's the only thing missing to the answer to be a full answer to the question

Comment: @cauchy I extended my answer with their differences.

Answer (score 1):

The simples way to use `std::chrono` to measure execution time is this:

```
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

/*
* multiple iterations of the code you want to benchmark - 
* make sure the optimizer doesn't eliminate the whole code
*/

auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

std::cout << "Execution time (us): " << duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start).count() << std::endl;
```